# D/B 'self' and <ClassName> to bind a function inside the class itself. (singleton in python)

Tags: python, variables, singleton, global-variables

This question may look silly(since I am new to python), but can you guys tell me what is the difference between self and classname when Binding?

```
class OnlyOne(object):

  class __OnlyOne:
    def __init__(self):
       self.val = None

    def __str__(self):
       return ´self´ + self.val

 instance = None

 def __new__(cls): # __new__ always a classmethod
    if not OnlyOne.instance:
      OnlyOne.instance = OnlyOne.__OnlyOne()
            return OnlyOne.instance

 def __getattr__(self, name):
     return getattr(self.instance, name)

 def __setattr__(self, name):
      return setattr(self.instance, name)
```

Here, I usually use Instance as self... What is the difference between using self and Only one... my intuition tells me that, it is a global variable.... if it is a global variable, it does not make sense at all(I will edit this, if its a global variable). Thanks!!

Comment: Usually there is no good reason to use singletons in python. If you need a singleton you most likely don't need a class at all! Besides that, please indent your code in a consistent way, preferably 4 spaces like suggested in PEP-8

Comment: ^ I am just learning design patterns in python(Thinking in Python, by Bruce Eckel).. I don't know what singleton pattern is, even though, I am a C++ guy...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've got a handle on your code ... The way it works is that when the constructor is called:

```
a = OnlyOne()  #call constructor.  This implicitly calls __new__
```

At this point, `__new__` checks the class to see if an instance has been created (instance isn't None).  If it hasn't been created, it creates an instance and puts it in the `instance` class attribute.  Then the `instance` class attribute is returned which is then passed into your methods as `self`.

I think that if you actually need a singleton, then there's something fishy (lazy) about your program design.  Singletons allow information to propagate throughout your program in strange ways (Imagine functions `foo` and `bar` both which create an instance of `OnlyOne`.  Changes you make in `foo` show up when you call `bar`) -- It's somewhat akin to monkey patching.

If, after rethinking your design for a few months, you decide that you really do need a singleton, you can create some sort of factory class which is a lot more transparent...

Comment: ^Thanks for your comment, I am reading DP book cover to cover..... I would really like to see, if you have any videos/lectures that talks about singleton.. & why we should not use it.... thanks.... :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand your second question (the one about using OnlyOne instead of self).  As far as why you shouldn't have singletons, I think that the problem is that it goes against the principle of encapsulation.  You can mutate your singleton in a function, not return it, (not even have it as an input argument) and that can have effects later in the code.